# Build image using Turtle World, python

Tags: python, image, turtle-graphics

Here are my code that uses instruction from a text file to build an image... the instruction assign a turtle and a direction x and y, for example: 1, 100, 100. Uses the turtle number one this turtle goes to x = 100 and y = 100.

```
from swampy.TurtleWorld import *
  def draw_to(t,x,y,steps):

x_diff = x - t.get_x() 
x_step = 1.0*x_diff/steps 
y_diff = y - t.get_y()
y_step = 1.0*y_diff/steps
for step in range(steps):
 t.fd(x_step)
 t.lt()
 t.fd(y_step)
 t.rt()

def process (s,tlist):
parts = s.split(',')
t = tlist[int(parts[0])-1]
x = int(parts[1])
y = int(parts[2])
draw_to(t,x,y,50)


fturtles = open('turtles.txt','r') 
instructions = fturtles.readlines()
fturtles.close()


world = TurtleWorld()


turtle_list = []
num_turtles = int(instructions[0])
for tNum in range(num_turtles):
new_turtle = Turtle(world)
new_turtle.set_delay(0.01)
turtle_list.append(new_turtle)

 for lineNum in range(1,len(instructions)):
   process(instructions[lineNum],turtle_list)
   print "just processed", instructions[lineNum]


 wait_for_user()
```

The code works fine, the problem is i tried to improve the functionality by changing the color of the pen of turtle, for example, in text file if i put : 1,100, 100, red, it will tell the turtle to use the color red. I tried to use that in a new function but i dont have any idea how to do that. If somebody can help me to clarify how to do that, it will be aprecciated.

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your code.  Also, could you show what it is you tried and did not work?

Comment: i did that  

    def colors():
   t.set_pen_color(), 

and tried to add this function in the process part but the only thing i got is : t is not defined, what is strange because t was used before in the function draw_to

Answer (score 0):

How about redefining your `process()` function as follows:

```
STEPS = 50
# ...
def process(instruction, turtle_list):
    index, x, y, color = instruction.split(',')
    t = turtle_list[int(index) - 1]
    t.set_pen_color(color.strip())
    draw_to(t, int(x), int(y), STEPS)
```

Using a simple turtle.txt file:

```
3
1, 100, 100, red
2, 100, 0, blue
3, 0, 100, green
```

I get:

[image]

My rework of your code follows but note that I used Python 3 and the turtle module that comes with it, not TurtleWorld, but most things map over fairly well:

```
import sys
from turtle import *

class TurtleWorld(Turtle):
    """ for Turtle World compatibility """

    def set_pen_color(self, *args):
        return self.pencolor(*args)

    def get_x(self): return self.xcor()

    def get_y(self): return self.ycor()

STEPS = 50
DELAY = 0
instruction_filename = sys.argv[1]

def draw_to(t, x, y, steps):
    x_diff = x - t.get_x() 
    x_step = x_diff / float(steps)
    y_diff = y - t.get_y()
    y_step = y_diff / float(steps)
    for step in range(steps):
        t.fd(x_step)
        t.lt(90)
        t.fd(y_step)
        t.rt(90)

def process(instruction, turtle_list):
    index, x, y, color = instruction.split(',')
    t = turtle_list[int(index) - 1]
    t.set_pen_color(color.strip())
    draw_to(t, int(x), int(y), STEPS)

instruction_file = open(instruction_filename) 
instructions = instruction_file.readlines()
instruction_file.close()

turtle_list = []
num_turtles = int(instructions[0])
for tNum in range(num_turtles):
    new_turtle = TurtleWorld()
    turtle_list.append(new_turtle)
delay(DELAY)

for instruction in instructions[1:]:
    process(instruction, turtle_list)
    print("just processed", instruction)

exitonclick()
```

Comment: just a question.. it is possible to get the code more specific ( for example, increase speed of drawing) and just use the function process to read it?

Comment: @CesarHoffmann, the delay in drawing seems to be the _steps_, perhaps if you could explain (in a new post) why you're using the steps and not just drawing the line, that might help folks give you suggestions.  Yes, `process()` could be modified to take the entire list of instructions or even the file as an argument and do all the processing.